# Isafter insert code get ecucute on after insert and after update

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger which needs to perform some logic only after insert, and some logic only after an update.

I have defined my Trigger as (after insert, after update). How can I control the execution of the trigger code depending on whether it was an insert or an update event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trigger, and you want one piece of code to run when the trigger is after insert and a different piece of code to run when it is after update?

```
trigger MyFirstTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

   if (Trigger.isAfter) {
       if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
           // do the after update related functionality
       }
       if (Trigger.isInsert) {
           // do the after insert related functionality
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: @Dougb your understanding of English is awesome! :P